# implementing rapidminer as a java application

Tags: java, rapidminer, user-interface

Designed a model for decision tree using rapidminer 5.2
i want to implement and view the result using java
I used xml generated from rapidminer and run the proces in java as process.run()
But i want to see my decision tree using java

Answer (score 1):

Try this example out:

```
package rm.rapidi.com;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import com.rapidminer.Process;
import com.rapidminer.RapidMiner;
import com.rapidminer.RapidMiner.ExecutionMode;
import com.rapidminer.RepositoryProcessLocation;
import com.rapidminer.gui.renderer.Renderer;
import com.rapidminer.gui.renderer.RendererService;
import com.rapidminer.operator.IOContainer;
import com.rapidminer.operator.IOObject;
import com.rapidminer.operator.OperatorException;
import com.rapidminer.report.Renderable;
import com.rapidminer.report.Reportable;
import com.rapidminer.repository.Entry;
import com.rapidminer.repository.ProcessEntry;
import com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryException;
import com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation;
import com.rapidminer.tools.XMLException;

public class PlotterTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.EMBEDDED_WITHOUT_UI);
    RapidMiner.init();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Decision Tree Renderer Test");
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(label));
    try {
        RepositoryLocation location;
        RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
        RapidMiner.init();
        location = new RepositoryLocation("//RapidMinerRepository/PlotterTest");
        Entry entry = location.locateEntry();
        if (entry instanceof ProcessEntry) {
            Process process = new RepositoryProcessLocation(location).load(null);

            IOContainer ioResult = process.run();
            IOObject result = ioResult.getElementAt(0); // or whatever index you need
            String name = RendererService.getName(result.getClass());
            List<Renderer> renderers = RendererService.getRenderers(name);
            for (Renderer renderer : renderers) { // you don't really need to
                // iterate over this, it's
                // probably only one anyway
                // ;)
                IOContainer dummy = new IOContainer();
                // edit size of image here
                int imgWidth = 1600;
                int imgHeight = 950;
                Reportable reportable = renderer.createReportable(result, dummy, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                if (reportable instanceof Renderable) {
                    Renderable renderable = (Renderable) reportable;
                    renderable.prepareRendering();
                    int preferredWidth = renderable.getRenderWidth(800);
                    int preferredHeight = renderable.getRenderHeight(800);
                    final BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                    // scale to whatever you need
                    graphics.scale(2, 2);
                    renderable.render(graphics, preferredWidth, preferredHeight);
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperatorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Using the following XML (Or similar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.005">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" height="60" name="Retrieve" width="90" x="45" y="75">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Sonar"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="decision_tree" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" height="76" name="Decision Tree" width="90" x="179" y="75"/>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve" from_port="output" to_op="Decision Tree" to_port="training set"/>
      <connect from_op="Decision Tree" from_port="model" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```