# how to convert the rapidminer generated xml to it's java code (in rapidminer)

Tags: java, xml, rapidminer

The below link has some xml code of a Decision tree model. Please let me know how it got converted to the java code, which is also there in the below link.

[implementing rapidminer as a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928769/implementing-rapidminer-as-a-java-application)

thanks,
Ravi Sankar

Answer (score 0):

The XML is a RapidMiner process that needs to be run to create a decision tree model.

The Java code looks like it is a plotter that will take the output from the XML process after it has run and plot the decision tree.

The Java code will find the XML process to run by looking in the repository at a certain location (//RapidMinerRepository/PlotterTest). The result of running this will be plotted.